# AWS Lambda Functions and AWS API Gateway(custom domain name) path redundancy/conflict

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am trying to remove the redundant path which is used in both my serverless configuration and aws api gateway mapping.

Problem:
Login serverless yaml
`serverless.yml`

```
frameworkversion: '>1.8'
service: ${stage}-login

provider:
name: aws
runtime: nodejs10.x
timeout: 12


functions: 
  login: 
    name: login
    handler: login.handler
    events: 
      - http: 
          path: login
          cors: true
          integration: lambda
          request:
            passThrough: WHEN_NO_MATCH
            template:
              application/json:
              <response omitted>
plugins:
 - serverless-offline
```

API mapping to my custom domain

1. API - login-dev
2. Stage - dev
3. Path(optional) - login

Goal:
Lambda Functions :

1. login - {base url}/dev/login
2. register - {base url}/dev/register

What happened:

1. login {base url}/dev/login/login
2. register - {base url}/dev/register/register

Actions taken:

1. Tried to remove the Path(optional) but it would not allow me to add another lambda function if path is omitted.
2. Tried to proxy(unsure if this works the way i understand it) but it doesn;t allow because an error shows that {login} is used in one of my lambda function parameters.
3. Removed path in serverless yaml configuration file and replaced it with blank or / - but not an option for me because i need to keep the existing configuration.

Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this:

```
functions: 
  login: 
    name: login
    handler: login.handler
    events: 
      - http: 
          path: /login
```

................

By adding a **"/"** in the starting of path.

Comment: Though I would really like to avoid altering/modifying existing configuration but i tried to do the above and it still mapped to login/login and login shows missing authentication error.
Thanks though

Comment: @FSDave If possible, can upload whole .yml code, so that it would be easy to debug.

Comment: sure @KnowledgeGainer, I provide.